# Upload files under same CID to IPFS

Tags: ipfs

I'm looking to create an NFT project with 10k pieces, each piece should be made available as soon as the token was minted, therefore I want to call upload the JSON object to IPFS under the same hash as I've seen in other projects.

This means that when the item was minted a new file will be uploaded to:

```
ipfs://<CID>/1
```

the seconds minting will create token 2 and then a new file will be uploaded to

```
ipfs://<CID>/2
```

How is it possible to be done with ipfs or pinata api?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it into a .car [Web 3 Storage How to Work With Car Files](https://docs.web3.storage/how-tos/work-with-car-files/)

Answer (score 0):

Update: I just reread the last part of the question.

I found this here (https://docs.pinata.cloud/api-pinning/pin-file) :

```
wrapWithDirectory - Wrap your content inside of a directory when adding to IPFS. This allows users to retrieve content via a filename instead of just a hash. For a more detailed explanation, see this informative blogpost. Valid options are: true or false
```

I'm pretty sure that you can do this with `ipfs add /PATH/TO/CONTENT/* -w`

I'm still exploring with IPFS, but this sounds like what you are looking for.